# you have had a giant win streak -- pronunciation of "a"

Tags: articles, pronunciation

*you have had a giant win streak* -- pronunciation of "a"

Here we are emphasising the greatness of the achievement. So it is natural and very common in such situations to say *a* in the strong form /ei/. Am I right?

Edit: thanks for the contributions.
But about this case here
https://youtu.be/xgs5gOCpsAE?t=100
"you have had a giant year"
(he both says "ei" and the sentence stress falls on "giant")

Comment: [a giant winn**ing** streak]

Comment: *You've had a **long / good / big / real / remarkable winning streak***. It's always ***winning streak***, never ***win streak***, and "giant" isn't a very common "intensifier" for this context. Only place stress on ***a*** (changing it from a neutral schwa to an emphatic diphthong) if you're using it (instead of more natural ***one***) to draw a contrast between ***that single winning streak*** and one or more (possibly "hypothetical") ***other*** very good winning streaks.

Comment: One of many giant winning streaks: https://www.reddit.com/r/OverwatchUniversity/comments/9fo3or/i_just_fell_back_into_silver_after_a_giant/

Comment: While it's not perfectly proper and might sound a bit informal in an academic paper or such, I think both "win streak" and "giant win(ning) streak" sound perfectly natural to me. But I'm an American who is involved in a number of game communities, so both of those might be factors.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you stress the a, you are emphasizing the fact that there is *one* giant win streak. In other words, you're saying he's had less giant win streaks than others.

You should stress the "giant" instead.

Comment: Hey, could you see my edit?